# Issues with USB 3 harddrive enclosure

Tags: usb-drive, 16.10

I got myself a new "home server" that has USB 3 ports. Unfortunately I am so far unable to use my external hard drive sitting in an USB 3 enclosure.

When I type `lsusb`, the device first shows up in the list. Theoretically I should see it now as `/dev/sdb` but it does not.

I watched what happens when I plug in the device using `dmesg`:

```
    [ 2736.092148] usb 2-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 28 using xhci_hcd
    [ 2736.113755] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=18a5, idProduct=022a
    [ 2736.113770] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=10, Product=11, SerialNumber=3
    [ 2736.113782] usb 2-1: Product: Desktop USB3.0 Drive
    [ 2736.113792] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: Verbatim
    [ 2736.113801] usb 2-1: SerialNumber: xxx
    [ 2736.125431] usb 2-1: Enable of device-initiated U2 failed.
    [ 2736.125891] usb-storage 2-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
    [ 2736.126544] scsi host2: usb-storage 2-1:1.0
    [ 2736.304098] usb 2-1: USB disconnect, device number 28
    [ 2736.568244] usb 2-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 29 using xhci_hcd
    [ 2736.589563] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=18a5, idProduct=022a
    [ 2736.589580] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=10, Product=11, SerialNumber=3
    [ 2736.589591] usb 2-1: Product: Desktop USB3.0 Drive
    [ 2736.589603] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: Verbatim
    [ 2736.589611] usb 2-1: SerialNumber: xxx
    [ 2736.591618] usb-storage 2-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
    [ 2736.592407] scsi host2: usb-storage 2-1:1.0
    [ 2738.131280] scsi 2:0:0:0: Direct-Access     SAMSUNG  HD103SJ          0010 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2 CCS
    [ 2738.133637] sd 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
    [ 2738.134622] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Sector size 0 reported, assuming 512.
    [ 2738.134650] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] 1953525168 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/932 GiB)
    [ 2738.134660] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] 0-byte physical blocks
    [ 2738.135187] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
    [ 2738.135204] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 28 00 00 00
    [ 2738.316463] usb 2-1: USB disconnect, device number 29
    [ 2738.336520] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Asking for cache data failed
    [ 2738.336532] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
    [ 2738.337251] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
    [ 2738.337256] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense not available.
    [ 2738.337314] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
    [ 2738.652616] usb 2-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 30 using xhci_hcd
    [ 2738.674111] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=18a5, idProduct=022a
    [ 2738.674128] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=10, Product=11, SerialNumber=3
    [ 2738.674139] usb 2-1: Product: Desktop USB3.0 Drive
    [ 2738.674150] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: Verbatim
    [ 2738.674158] usb 2-1: SerialNumber: xxx
    [ 2738.676243] usb-storage 2-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
    [ 2738.680823] scsi host2: usb-storage 2-1:1.0
    [ 2740.352153] scsi 2:0:0:0: Direct-Access     SAMSUNG  HD103SJ          0010 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2 CCS
    [ 2740.354837] sd 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
    [ 2740.355047] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Sector size 0 reported, assuming 512.
    [ 2740.355074] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] 1953525168 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/932 GiB)
    [ 2740.355084] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] 0-byte physical blocks
    [ 2740.355737] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
    [ 2740.355755] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 28 00 00 00
    [ 2740.356212] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
    [ 2740.356241] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
    [ 2740.363230] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Sector size 0 reported, assuming 512.
    [ 2740.985374] usb 2-1: USB disconnect, device number 30
    [ 2741.000802] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
    [ 2741.000810] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
    [ 2741.000814] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 0
    [ 2741.000823] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, async page read
    [ 2741.000895] ldm_validate_partition_table(): Disk read failed.
    [ 2741.000931] Dev sdb: unable to read RDB block 0
    [ 2741.000989]  sdb: unable to read partition table
    [ 2741.001413] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
    [ 2741.001417] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense not available.
    [ 2741.001467] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
    [ 2741.509069] usb 2-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 31 using xhci_hcd
    [ 2741.530629] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=18a5, idProduct=022a
    [ 2741.530644] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=10, Product=11, SerialNumber=3
    [ 2741.530655] usb 2-1: Product: Desktop USB3.0 Drive
    [ 2741.530666] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: Verbatim
    [ 2741.530674] usb 2-1: SerialNumber: xxx
    [ 2741.532731] usb-storage 2-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
    [ 2741.535147] scsi host2: usb-storage 2-1:1.0
    [ 2743.067191] scsi 2:0:0:0: Direct-Access     SAMSUNG  HD103SJ          0010 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2 CCS
    [ 2743.069626] sd 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
    [ 2743.070646] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Sector size 0 reported, assuming 512.
    [ 2743.070673] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] 1953525168 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/932 GiB)
    [ 2743.070683] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] 0-byte physical blocks
    [ 2743.071207] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
    [ 2743.071224] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 28 00 00 00
    [ 2743.071785] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
    [ 2743.071811] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
    [ 2743.073404] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Sector size 0 reported, assuming 512.
    [ 2743.692569] usb 2-1: USB disconnect, device number 31
    [ 2743.733299] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
    [ 2743.733322] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
    [ 2743.733333] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 0
    [ 2743.733362] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, async page read
    [ 2743.733534] ldm_validate_partition_table(): Disk read failed.
    [ 2743.733624] Dev sdb: unable to read RDB block 0
    [ 2743.733710]  sdb: unable to read partition table
    [ 2743.734204] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
    [ 2743.734212] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense not available.
    [ 2743.734283] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
    [ 2744.213423] usb 2-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 32 using xhci_hcd
    [ 2744.234786] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=18a5, idProduct=022a
    [ 2744.234802] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=10, Product=11, SerialNumber=3
    [ 2744.234813] usb 2-1: Product: Desktop USB3.0 Drive
    [ 2744.234824] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: Verbatim
    [ 2744.234832] usb 2-1: SerialNumber: xxx
    [ 2744.237011] usb-storage 2-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
    [ 2744.244433] scsi host2: usb-storage 2-1:1.0
    [ 2745.949561] usb 2-1: USB disconnect, device number 32
    [ 2751.470301] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
    [ 2756.846883] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
    [ 2757.054858] usb 2-1: device not accepting address 33, error -62
    [ 2762.479388] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
    [ 2767.855778] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
    [ 2768.063718] usb 2-1: device not accepting address 34, error -62
    [ 2773.488111] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
    [ 2778.864381] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
    [ 2779.072321] usb 2-1: device not accepting address 35, error -62
    [ 2784.496531] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
    [ 2789.872669] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
    [ 2790.080633] usb 2-1: device not accepting address 36, error -62
    [ 2790.108789] usb usb2-port1: unable to enumerate USB device
```

The odd thing is that it seems like the device is detected at first correctly, then it is disconnected multiple times and finally things go really south and the device is gone. `lsusb` now does not show the enclosure anymore.

Another USB 3 device, a smaller hard drive, produces several errors when plugging in but finally the device shows up as `/dev/sdb`

I am using kernel 4.9.0-040900-generic (same issues with the 4.8.* kernel) on a 64 bit machine, ubuntu 16.10.

Regards

Comment: Do you have a USB2 port to try this disk on? Does the disk work on any other computer? How did you prepare the disk for use?

Comment: - Disk+enclosure were used on another Linux Server on a USB 3 port for 2 years. No problems so far.

- I verified if the drive is alive using a USB 3 - SATA adapter. Works well. 

- I removed the original hard drive from the enclosure and put another hard drive in (the original drive is ext4 which the Mac doesn't understand). I could use this combo on a old Macbook with USB 2 ports without problems. So I recon the enclosure itself is fine as well.

Comment: Drives put into, or taken out of, external enclosures require re-initialization most of the time. This is due to the USB-to-SATA module located inside the enclosure. If you never did that to the drive that you were originally trying to use, then you'll need to backup data (if there is any) when installed in its original location, then put the drive into the external enclosure, re-initialize the drive, and restore the data.

Comment: What are you referring to with "re-initialization"? You are not talking about wiping the drive, creating new partitions and file systems? Because I cannot imagine that the SATA Controller does understand things like a partition or a file system? That thing "lives" beyond file system level. Furthermore: I could not even initialize (when understanding this term as "wiping") the hard drive, as fdisk -l does not show the device.

Comment: PS: I found this here: http://www.zedt.eu/tech/linux/soft-resetting-sata-devices-linux/ Is this what you are talking about @heynnema?

Comment: No, I'm not talking about the last link that you provided. Let me confirm... the original drive in EXT4 format won't mount when in the external enclosure, but when removed from the enclosure, and attached using another USB-to-SATA convertor, the drive works fine, yes? To wipe the drive, the easiest is to start `gparted` and lay down a new MBR/GPT partition table, and then add back the required partitions. Does `gparted` see the drive in the external enclosure? Can you `fsck` the drive?

Comment: Sorry for the late response: I have been on a trip. What you wrote above is correct. However, I cannot wipe the drive as I need the data on it. In the meantime I got a new SATA-USB adapter and can use the drive (with all of the valuable data on it) on my new computer. I have no idea why the old enclosure does not work. But sometimes it is better to spend 20$ instead of messing around hours and hours ;-) Thanks @heynnema